# Linux hangs at first start with black screen, the second is ok

Tags: linux-kernel, crash

Everytime I start Linux the system hangs with a black screen and no keyboard, then I must reboot with magic sysrq, and then the boot completes correctly. 
At the end of `kern.log` I got (this is only a part of all the output for the limits here):

```
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.855075] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.857107] rcu:  1-....: (1 GPs behind) idle=1aa/0/0x3 softirq=3143/3144 fqs=2616 
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859156]   (t=5252 jiffies g=1321 q=4100)
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859158] NMI backtrace for cpu 1
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859162] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Not tainted 5.4.0-1-amd64 #1 Debian 5.4.6-1
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859163] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/M3N78-VM, BIOS 1309    09/11/2009
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859164] Call Trace:
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859168]  <IRQ>
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859177]  dump_stack+0x66/0x90
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859180]  nmi_cpu_backtrace.cold+0x14/0x53
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859185]  ? lapic_can_unplug_cpu.cold+0x3e/0x3e
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859187]  nmi_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0xf6/0xf8
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859191]  rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0x8f/0xbd
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859194]  rcu_sched_clock_irq.cold+0x1b2/0x3ab
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859197]  ? trigger_load_balance+0x5a/0x210
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859200]  update_process_times+0x24/0x50
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859203]  tick_sched_handle+0x22/0x60
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859207]  tick_sched_timer+0x38/0x80
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859209]  ? tick_sched_do_timer+0x60/0x60
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859211]  __hrtimer_run_queues+0xf6/0x270
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859214]  hrtimer_interrupt+0x10e/0x240
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859217]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x6c/0x130
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859220]  apic_timer_interrupt+0xf/0x20
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859223] RIP: 0010:net_rx_action+0x354/0x3c0
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859227] Code: 37 fe ff ff 48 8b 4c 24 18 48 8d 44 24 30 48 89 6c 24 38 48 89 45 00 48 89 4d 08 48 89 29 e9 18 fe ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <e9> f2 fe ff ff 48 8b 5c 24 10 48 83 7b 38 00 0f 85 2c fe ff ff 48
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859228] RSP: 0018:ffffbf72c000fee0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859231] RAX: 0000000000000008 RBX: ffff99bb67aab680 RCX: 0000000000000003
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859232] RDX: ffff99bb5f3188d0 RSI: ffffbf72c000ff10 RDI: 0000000000000000
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859234] RBP: ffff99bb5f3188d0 R08: ffff99bb67aab680 R09: ffff99bb67aab680
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859235] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffbf72c000ff00
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859236] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: 0000000000000040
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859238]  ? apic_timer_interrupt+0xa/0x20
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859243]  __do_softirq+0xe6/0x2e9
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859247]  ? handle_irq_event_percpu+0x72/0x80
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859251]  irq_exit+0xa6/0xb0
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859253]  do_IRQ+0x58/0xe0
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859256]  common_interrupt+0xf/0xf
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859258]  </IRQ>
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859260] RIP: 0010:native_safe_halt+0xe/0x10
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859262] Code: 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 e9 07 00 00 00 0f 00 2d 36 7a 46 00 f4 c3 66 90 e9 07 00 00 00 0f 00 2d 26 7a 46 00 fb f4 <c3> 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 54 55 53 e8 32 bf 95 ff 65 8b 2d db f4 06
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859264] RSP: 0018:ffffbf72c0083ea8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffda
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859265] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000001
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859267] RDX: 000000024b4526a5 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffffff95806a40
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859268] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859269] R10: ffff99bb67a97608 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff99bb669fb700
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859270] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff99bb669fb700
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859275]  ? __tick_broadcast_oneshot_control+0x14c/0x1f0
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859277]  default_idle+0x1a/0x140
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859280]  amd_e400_idle+0x22/0x40
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859283]  do_idle+0x1fa/0x270
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859286]  cpu_startup_entry+0x19/0x20
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859289]  start_secondary+0x15f/0x1b0
Mar  6 08:08:34 myhost kernel: [   30.859292]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.975179] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched detected expedited stalls on CPUs/tasks: { 1-... } 5396 jiffies s: 105 root: 0x2/.
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.979411] rcu: blocking rcu_node structures:
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983566] Task dump for CPU 1:
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983570] swapper/1       R  running task        0     0      1 0x80004008
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983586] Call Trace:
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983609]  ? native_safe_halt+0xe/0x10
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983619]  ? __tick_broadcast_oneshot_control+0x14c/0x1f0
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983624]  ? default_idle+0x1a/0x140
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983639]  ? amd_e400_idle+0x22/0x40
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983645]  ? do_idle+0x1fa/0x270
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983651]  ? cpu_startup_entry+0x19/0x20
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983656]  ? start_secondary+0x15f/0x1b0
Mar  6 08:08:35 myhost kernel: [   31.983663]  ? secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Mar  6 08:08:37 myhost kernel: [   34.127111] CE: hpet increased min_delta_ns to 11521 nsec
Mar  6 08:08:37 myhost kernel: [   34.806019] EXT4-fs (sdc4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391069] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [swapper/1:0]
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391076] Modules linked in: rfkill uas usb_storage snd_hda_codec_via snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc hid_generic usbhid hid sr_mod cdrom edac_mce_amd kvm_amd ccp rng_core kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt irqbypass ohci_pci snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep wmi_bmof ohci_hcd pcspkr ehci_pci snd_pcm k10temp ehci_hcd snd_timer 8139too usbcore snd 8139cp nv_tco sg firewire_ohci soundcore forcedeth mii usb_common i2c_nforce2 pata_amd floppy asus_atk0110 acpi_cpufreq firewire_sbp2 firewire_core crc_itu_t ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic sd_mod radeon i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper ahci libahci ata_generic mxm_wmi drm libata scsi_mod serio_raw evdev video wmi button
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391132] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Not tainted 5.4.0-1-amd64 #1 Debian 5.4.6-1
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391133] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/M3N78-VM, BIOS 1309    09/11/2009
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391135] RIP: 0010:net_rx_action+0x354/0x3c0
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391137] Code: 37 fe ff ff 48 8b 4c 24 18 48 8d 44 24 30 48 89 6c 24 38 48 89 45 00 48 89 4d 08 48 89 29 e9 18 fe ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <e9> f2 fe ff ff 48 8b 5c 24 10 48 83 7b 38 00 0f 85 2c fe ff ff 48
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391138] RSP: 0018:ffffbf72c000fee0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391140] RAX: 0000000000000008 RBX: ffff99bb67aab680 RCX: 0000000000000003
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391142] RDX: ffff99bb5f3188d0 RSI: ffffbf72c000ff10 RDI: 0000000000000000
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391143] RBP: ffff99bb5f3188d0 R08: ffff99bb67aab680 R09: ffff99bb67aab680
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391144] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffffbf72c000ff00
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391145] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: 0000000000000040
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391147] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff99bb67a80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391148] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391150] CR2: 0000561cd97b7318 CR3: 000000011100a000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391151] Call Trace:
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391152]  <IRQ>
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391155]  __do_softirq+0xe6/0x2e9
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391159]  ? handle_irq_event_percpu+0x72/0x80
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391162]  irq_exit+0xa6/0xb0
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391164]  do_IRQ+0x58/0xe0
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391166]  common_interrupt+0xf/0xf
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391168]  </IRQ>
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391170] RIP: 0010:native_safe_halt+0xe/0x10
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391172] Code: 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 e9 07 00 00 00 0f 00 2d 36 7a 46 00 f4 c3 66 90 e9 07 00 00 00 0f 00 2d 26 7a 46 00 fb f4 <c3> 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 54 55 53 e8 32 bf 95 ff 65 8b 2d db f4 06
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391173] RSP: 0018:ffffbf72c0083ea8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffda
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391175] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000001
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391176] RDX: 000000024b4526a5 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffffff95806a40
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391177] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391178] R10: ffff99bb67a97608 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff99bb669fb700
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391179] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff99bb669fb700
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391183]  ? __tick_broadcast_oneshot_control+0x14c/0x1f0
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391186]  default_idle+0x1a/0x140
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391188]  amd_e400_idle+0x22/0x40
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391191]  do_idle+0x1fa/0x270
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391194]  cpu_startup_entry+0x19/0x20
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391196]  start_secondary+0x15f/0x1b0
Mar  6 08:08:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391198]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Mar  6 08:09:27 myhost kernel: [   84.391068] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [swapper/1:0]
Mar  6 08:09:27 myhost kernel: [   84.391074] Modules linked in: rfkill uas usb_storage snd_hda_codec_via snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc hid_generic usbhid hid sr_mod cdrom edac_mce_amd kvm_amd ccp rng_core kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt irqbypass ohci_pci snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep wmi_bmof ohci_hcd pcspkr ehci_pci snd_pcm k10temp ehci_hcd snd_timer 8139too usbcore snd 8139cp nv_tco sg firewire_ohci soundcore forcedeth mii usb_common i2c_nforce2 pata_amd floppy asus_atk0110 acpi_cpufreq firewire_sbp2 firewire_core crc_itu_t ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic sd_mod radeon i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper ahci libahci ata_generic mxm_wmi drm libata scsi_mod serio_raw evdev video wmi button
.
.
.
.
Mar  6 15:37:38 myhost kernel: [   34.943062] EXT4-fs (sdd4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391075] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [swapper/1:0]
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391078] Modules linked in: rfkill uas usb_storage snd_hda_codec_via snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common videodev mc hid_generic usbhid hid sr_mod cdrom edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm_amd ccp snd_hda_intel snd_intel_nhlt ohci_pci rng_core snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core kvm ohci_hcd ehci_pci snd_hwdep ehci_hcd snd_pcm irqbypass wmi_bmof pcspkr 8139too snd_timer k10temp 8139cp snd nv_tco soundcore usbcore pata_amd sg firewire_ohci forcedeth mii usb_common i2c_nforce2 asus_atk0110 floppy acpi_cpufreq firewire_sbp2 firewire_core crc_itu_t ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic sd_mod radeon i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper ahci ata_generic libahci libata drm scsi_mod serio_raw video mxm_wmi evdev wmi button
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391135] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Not tainted 5.4.0-1-amd64 #1 Debian 5.4.6-1
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391136] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/M3N78-VM, BIOS 1309    09/11/2009
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391138] RIP: 0010:net_rx_action+0x354/0x3c0
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391141] Code: 37 fe ff ff 48 8b 4c 24 18 48 8d 44 24 30 48 89 6c 24 38 48 89 45 00 48 89 4d 08 48 89 29 e9 18 fe ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <e9> f2 fe ff ff 48 8b 5c 24 10 48 83 7b 38 00 0f 85 2c fe ff ff 48
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391142] RSP: 0018:ffff98a64000fee0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391144] RAX: 0000000000000008 RBX: ffff899767aab680 RCX: 0000000000000003
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391145] RDX: ffff899761b468d0 RSI: ffff98a64000ff10 RDI: 0000000000000000
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391146] RBP: ffff899761b468d0 R08: ffff899767aab680 R09: ffff899767aab680
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391148] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff98a64000ff00
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391149] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: 0000000000000040
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391150] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff899767a80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391152] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391153] CR2: 00007f1d4399d0d0 CR3: 0000000223926000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391154] Call Trace:
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391155]  <IRQ>
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391159]  __do_softirq+0xe6/0x2e9
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391162]  ? handle_irq_event_percpu+0x72/0x80
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391165]  irq_exit+0xa6/0xb0
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391167]  do_IRQ+0x58/0xe0
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391170]  common_interrupt+0xf/0xf
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391171]  </IRQ>
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391173] RIP: 0010:native_safe_halt+0xe/0x10
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391175] Code: 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 e9 07 00 00 00 0f 00 2d 36 7a 46 00 f4 c3 66 90 e9 07 00 00 00 0f 00 2d 26 7a 46 00 fb f4 <c3> 90 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 54 55 53 e8 32 bf 95 ff 65 8b 2d db f4 c6
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391176] RSP: 0018:ffff98a640083ea8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffda
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391178] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000001
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391179] RDX: 000000023fd37b18 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffffffa1c06a40
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391180] RBP: 0000000000000001 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391181] R10: ffff899767a97608 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8997669fc4c0
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391183] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8997669fc4c0
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391187]  ? __tick_broadcast_oneshot_control+0x14c/0x1f0
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391189]  default_idle+0x1a/0x140
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391192]  amd_e400_idle+0x22/0x40
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391194]  do_idle+0x1fa/0x270
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391197]  cpu_startup_entry+0x19/0x20
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391199]  start_secondary+0x15f/0x1b0
Mar  6 15:37:59 myhost kernel: [   56.391201]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Mar  6 15:38:18 myhost kernel: [   74.941266] sysrq: Emergency Sync
```

The system is pretty old (~10 year)
Linux amd64 Debian unstable with xfce
Board Name:        M3N78-VM  ASUSTeK bios  1309
Kernel release:    5.4.0-1-amd64
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 630 Processor (family: 0x10, model: 0x5, stepping: 0x2)
SMP Enabled:       Yes
RAM 8 GB
There are 4 disks:
an ssd, with GPT partition table, with the boot partition, /, /root, etc..., the system was recently installed there.
a harddisk (non ssd) sata with swap on it
two harddisk for data backup
trying to solve the problem I added to the boot kernel command line of grub
`fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes iommu=soft`
this didn't changed the boot problem.
I suspect that the problem is related to ssd.

Comment: Looks like a hardware hickup. It's sad but true, they happen. I even think the happen more often than under Windows. But this may be depended on the hardware used. I say it is the mainboard. Look at "Call Trace".

Comment: WGRM: maybe a bios update could be useful? now the version is 1309 but is available 1801, but flash is a risk

Comment: Exactly. Actually it should go well. But when i look at my second work station to my left.... Even with dual BIOS it got a worthless piece o....... The risk is on your site, but i have a goor feeling it could help.